# Delete a file in a directory except for first file (or specific file) in Python

Tags: python, find, delete-file, os.system, rm

I want to delete all files in a directory except for one file in python.
I used os.remove and os.system(with rm and fine), but all of them return errors.

Lets say I have a folder X and in there I have files named 1 2 3 4.
alongside folder X, I have main.py. in main.py how can I write a command to go to the folder and delete all files except for 1.

Thanks...

I tried

```
os.system(f"rm -v !('1')")
```

but it says ''rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.'

I tried

```
os.system(f"find ./X -not -name '1' -delete")
```

```
os.system(f"find /X -not -name '1' -delete")
```

```
os.system(f"find . -not -name '1' -delete")
```

```
os.system(f"find X -not -name '1' -delete")
```

But all of them says 'Parameter format not correct'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in Python using various functions from the *os* module rather than relying on *find*.

```
from os import chdir, listdir, remove, getcwd

def delete_from(directory: str, keep: list) -> None:
    cwd = getcwd()
    try:
        chdir(directory)
        for file in listdir():
            if not file in keep:
                remove(file)
    finally:
        chdir(cwd)
```

Call this with a path to the directory to be affected and a list of files (basenames only) to be retained.

e.g.,

```
delete_from('X', ['1'])
```